# Perl: Print the lines of the file in order of length, lines of equal length should be sorted alphabetically

Tags: perl

I'm writing a perl program that sorts lines in a file according to their length, lines of equal length should be sorted alphabetically.

Below is what I have tried. I'm not exactly sure about the use of length $a and length $b and the cmp function. My code is also not compiling, could someone please help me with this. I'm pretty new to perl so a bit of explanation would be helpful! Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

if (@ARGV != 1){
    die "Usage $0: <file>\n";
}else { 
    foreach $file(@ARGV){
    open my $f, '>', $file or die "Cannot open $file: $!\n";
    my @lines = <$f>;
    close $f;

        foreach $line(@lines){
            if (length $a == length $b){
                @length_line = sort(length $a cmp length $b);
            } else {
                @length_line = sort(length $a <=> length $b);
            }
        }
    }
    print "@length_line\n";
}
```

Comment: (1) The shown code opens files for writing, with `>`.  That would truncate each file first! (Typo in posting?)  (2) There is no need for an explicit if-else -- just check `die "Usage ... " if ...` and then the rest of the code goes.  (3) _Always_ have `use warnings;` and `use strict;` at the beginning.  (4) The attempted sorting is completely wrong, clarified in the asnwer. One thing: the `$a` and `$b` have their meaning only _inside_ the `sort`'s block.

Answer (score 3):

```
@length_line = sort(length $a cmp length $b);
```

Probably not what you intended -- the cmp operator shouldn't be working on the length function's output -- it should work on the string's actual value.

I think you can set up a single compound sort routine, on the order of

```
@sorted_lines = sort {((length $a) <=> (length $b)) || ($a cmp $b)} @lines;
```

Then, skip the whole loop -- it's unnecessary.
End with

```
print "$_\n" foreach @sorted_lines;
```

Comment: `sort { length($a) <=> length($b) || $a cmp $b }` is sufficient, and the intent is clear without the need for additional parens.

Answer (score 0):

A few other comments:

```
print "@length_line\n";
```

1. Even if this array had what you wanted in it, you can't just print an array in Perl.  For debugging things, read up on the Data::Dumper package for this, so you could do something like

   print Dumper(@length_line) . "\n";
2. For your method of reading the file, you've got some problems.  Think your '>' is indicating you want to write the file, which doesn't seem right.  You could roll your own reading mechanism, or you could look into the File::Slurp package to do so, so you could read into @lines like this:

   my @lines = read_file $file, { slurp => 1 };
3. For getting yourself into writing good Perl, you probably want to turn on strict mode and warnings. Thought of that when I saw your foreach statements, which should really have a my inside them, like:

   foreach my $line (@lines)

Comment: "*you can't just print an array in Perl*" - Sure you can. It's just that `print @foo` (without quotes) outputs all elements next to each other (without any separator) and `"@foo"` is effectively the same as `join(" ", @foo)` (using a space as the separator). For debugging you probably want `Dumper(\@foo)`, not `Dumper(@foo)`.

Comment: Good point; I'm used to stumbling into references to arrays, which don't output their data.  [Edit: well, I guess they *do* output their data, it's just that "their data" isn't the useful bits to me]  BTW, tried it, and don't even get the space separator between the array elements on mine.  Wonder why you'd get different behavior?